# Relation between row and page in database

Tags: database

What is a relations between page and rows ?

1) One row could be inserted to one or more pages

2) One page could contain many rows.

Which one is true ? Is it database dependent ?

Answer (score 0):

A page in a database is a way to structure the data internally, not something that a user of a database needs to worry about. A row would generally only be in only one page, and a page could contain many rows -- as data. How this works is database dependent, write your own database and use pages as you prefer.

Perhaps you mean "table" in stead og "page"?

In relational databases, a table is defined by its columns, each column has a type, and a row is a list of values that match the column types.